# Android studio listview doesn't show

Tags: java, android, listview

Hello Im new to android studio and i probably made a silly mistake which i cant find. 
So basicaly i have made a tabbed activity with all the days and i want to make a list (I wanna make a custom schedule app which will have all the activities i do daily).My ListView doesn't show :(. What have i done wrong?

EditActivity class code : https://hastebin.com/amajusutid.java

```
package com.timemanagement.restrictedpower.timemanagement;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private  ViewPager mViewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_edit, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static String day(int id){
        switch (id) {
            case 1:
                return "Monday";
            case 2:
                return "Tuesday";
            case 3:
                return "Wednesday";
            case 4:
                return "Thirsday";
            case 5:
                return "Friday";
            case 6:
                return "Saturday";
            case 7:
                return "Sunday";
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit, container, false);

            ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.Activities);
            List<String> fruits_list = new ArrayList<String>();
            fruits_list.add("Apple");
            fruits_list.add("Strawberry");
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fruits_list);
            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            lv.invalidateViews();
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Day);
            int id = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            String day = day(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
            textView.setText(day);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 7;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "SECTION 1";
                case 1:
                    return "SECTION 2";
                case 2:
                    return "SECTION 3";
                case 3:
                    return "SECTION 4";
                case 4:
                    return "SECTION 5";
                case 5:
                    return "SECTION 6";
                case 6:
                    return "SECTION 7";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Xml code: https://hastebin.com/yapepideme.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#1234">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Activities"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ExpandableListView" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="5mm"
        android:id="@+id/Day" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textColor="#FFCC91"
        android:textSize="6mm"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I think you list is diplaying but your background color and textcolor of your listview item is same. check this. click or longpress on listview

Comment: And why you are taking View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit, container, false); rootView? you already have this View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit, container, false);
So just return v and remove rootView

Answer (score 1):

I have solved your problem, you have to change the height of the linear layout because it is hidden when the app bar layout is applied.Your listview should placed below the app bar layout.I have changed                    android:layout_height="300dp" ,
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"  in your linear layout.Now your listview is appearing.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#1234">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Activities"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ExpandableListView" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="5mm"
        android:id="@+id/Day" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textColor="#FFCC91"
        android:textSize="6mm"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Hmm still it shows nothing :/ . Also I'm sure that my linear layout wasn't hiding behind the app bar i could see it in my design page.